# Add padding to panel that is dock and has autoscroll

Tags: c#

I have a panel that is docked at the bottom of my form. This panel is set to AutoScroll so the scroll bars appear when needed.

I have a image that are dynamically added to this panel. Everything looks fine except the last image as on the very edge for the form here is an image for example:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can add a padding to the right side of the panel and yes I did try setting the panel right padding but that did not work.

Comment: Are you using WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms

Comment: have you tried playing with margins instead?

Comment: Yup, neither of them see to add any padding.

Comment: have you tried using the [SetAutoScrollMargin Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.setautoscrollmargin.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Thank you Mark Hall
The AutoScrollMargin property helped me and it was exactly the same issue as Robert

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. One can use `panel.SetAutoScrollMargin(W, H)` or change the `AutoScrollMargin` property in the Designer. Both do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TableLayoutPanel for the image container and then add the TableLayoutPanel in the Panel control.