# Scrolling panel visual issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, scroll

I have a panel which contains 6 pictureboxes. I set it to autoscroll. It looks like that:

[image]

When I scroll it to the right the last picturebox does not have space to the right:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add padding to panel that is dock and has autoscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085104/add-padding-to-panel-that-is-dock-and-has-autoscroll)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `panel` properties and select `AutoScrollMargin`. Set `Width` to what ever value you want. Thats it!

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]